# How do I type brackets [ ] on MacOs with tmux and a french keyboard layout?

Tags: macos, keyboard-layout, tmux

- My keyboard is a french apple extended keyboard
- To type brackets, I usually type `Alt+Shift+(` or `Alt+Shift+)`
- When I'm using `tmux` in a terminal window on MacOs Sierra, this doesn't work

What do I need to do to type brackets ? I've tried to unbind this combination in .tmux.conf, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Have you tried shift 9 & 0, just in case it is using an English layout; or 5 & [key to the right of 0] for French Azerty? See https://support.apple.com/HT201794 for keyboard layouts

Comment: sorry, square brackets...my bad. English keyboard would be the two keys to the right of P; french layout standard would be alt/shift 5 & alt/shift [key to the right of 0]

Comment: I've tried the two keys next to p (¨ and * on my keyboard), but it does not type square brackets. (my keyboard looks like this one https://support.apple.com/library/content/dam/edam/applecare/images/fr_FR/keyboards/french_numeric.png by the way)

Comment: ah, OK - was just an idea ... UK keyboard looks like this so I just wondered if the positions might work - https://support.apple.com/library/content/dam/edam/applecare/images/en_US/keyboards/british_notebook.png

Answer (score 1):

in iTerm2 you have to use your left alt key as a normal key, maybe you've set this up wrongfully?

Preferencens -> Profiles -> Default -> keys

[image: screenshot keys]